# Snake game- Snake built but not moving, coordinates not updating despite being written verbatim from tutorial

Tags: java, android-studio, coordinates

Edit:

I tried getting this to work again but I couldn't figure it out, I was wondering if there was something missing so this is the entirety of the code

```
public class GameEngine {

public static final int GameWidth = 28;
public static final int GameHeight = 42;

private List<Coordinate> walls = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Coordinate> snake = new ArrayList<>();

private Direction currentDirection  = Direction.East;

private GameState currentGameState = GameState.Running;

public void Update(){
    //snake
    switch (currentDirection){

        case North:
            UpdateSnake(0,-1);
            break;
        case East:
            UpdateSnake(1,0);
            break;
        case South:
            UpdateSnake(0,1);
            break;
        case West:
            UpdateSnake(-1,0);
            break;
    }

    for (Coordinate W: walls){
        if (snake.get(0).equals(W)){
            currentGameState = GameState.Lost;
        }
    }
}

public GameEngine() {


}

public void initGame() {



    AddSnake();
    AddWalls();
}



public TileType[][] getMap (){
    TileType[][] map = new TileType[GameWidth][GameHeight];

    for (int x = 0; x < GameWidth; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < GameHeight; y++)
        map [x][y] = TileType.Nothing;
    }

    for (Coordinate s: snake){
        map [s.getX()][s.getY()] = TileType.SnakeTail;
    }
    map[snake.get(0).getX()][snake.get(0).getY()] = TileType.SnakeHead;

    for (Coordinate wall: walls){
        map[wall.getX()][wall.getY()] = TileType.Wall;
    }
    return map;
}



private void UpdateSnake (int x, int y){
    TileType[][] map = getMap();

    for (int i = snake.size() -1 ; i > 0 ; i--){
        map[snake.get(0).getX()][snake.get(0).getY()] = TileType.SnakeTail;
        snake.get(i).setY(snake.get(i-1).getY());

    }


snake.get(0).setX(snake.get(0).getX()+x);
snake.get(0).setY(snake.get(0).getY()+y);
}

private void AddSnake(){

    snake.clear();


    snake.add(new Coordinate(7,7));
    snake.add(new Coordinate(6,7));
    snake.add(new Coordinate(5,7));
    snake.add(new Coordinate(4,7));
    snake.add(new Coordinate(3,7));
    snake.add(new Coordinate(2,7));
}

private void AddWalls() {
    for (int x = 0; x < GameWidth; x++) {
        walls.add(new Coordinate(x, 0));
        walls.add(new Coordinate(x, GameHeight - 1));
    }

    for (int y = 1; y < GameHeight; y++) {
        walls.add(new Coordinate(0, y));
        walls.add(new Coordinate(GameWidth - 1, y));
    }
}

public GameState getCurrentGameState() {
    return currentGameState;
}
```

I tried the answer below but there kept being errors and I can't understand why.

When I was attempting to put in the update map suggested the map was always underlined, as were the get functions

Answer (score 0):

The function `private void UpdateSnake (int x, int y){` does not update the current map tile. So you see nothing happens at all.

You need to update the tile map (the one returned from `public TileType[][] getMap ()` function) :

```
TileType[][] map = getMap(); // Do this when you start the game. Where you call `getMap()`, just store the reference to a variable `map`

private void UpdateSnake (int x, int y){

    // Set title of snake.get(snake.size() -1) to TileType.Nothing;
    Snake tail = snake.get(snake.size() - 1);
    map[tail.getX()][tail.get(Y)] = TileType.SnakeTail;

    for (int i = snake.size()-1; i > 0; i--){
         snake.get(i).setX(snake.get(i-1).getX());
         snake.get(i).setY(snake.get(i-1).getY());

    }
    snake.get(0).setX(snake.get(0).getX()+x);
    snake.get(0).setY(snake.get(0).getY()+y);

    // Set title of snake.get(1) to TileType.SnakeTail;
    map[snake.get(0).getX()][snake.get(0).get(Y)] = TileType.SnakeTail;
    // Set title of snake.get(0) to TileType.SnakeHead;
    map[snake.get(0).getX()][snake.get(0).get(Y)] = TileType.SnakeHead;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment,I think I must be misunderstanding though sorry

 'private void UpdateSnake (int x, int y){
    for (int i = snake.size()-1; i > 0; i--){
        snake.get(i).setX(snake.get(i-1).getX());
        snake.get(i).setY(snake.get(i-1).getY());

    }
    snake.get(0).setX(TileType.Nothing.getX()+x);
    snake.get(0).setY(TileType.Nothing.getY()+y);
    }'

Do you mean like this?

Comment: Sorry new to stack overlfow, meant the code to look like this:


`private void UpdateSnake (int x, int y){`
``
    `for (int i = snake.size()-1; i > 0; i--){`
``
        `snake.get(i).setX(snake.get(i-1).getX());`
``
        `snake.get(i).setY(snake.get(i-1).getY());`
``

    `}`
` `
   ` snake.get(0).setX(TileType.Nothing.getX()+x);`
` `
    `snake.get(0).setY(TileType.Nothing.getY()+y);`

Comment: I can't do it lol I'll edit it into the main body of the question

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, I only started android studio today, is there any chance you could write it out how it should be or do you need more information? I would be very appreciative

Comment: The rest of your code is good, you don't need to modify. You just have to fill the code for each comment line I left in my answer above (3 lines). My updated answer give you the sample code for the last comment line. I think it's easy for you to fill the rest

Comment: Is the new update along the right lines? Sorry I'm not very good at this

Comment: No no, you left the original code untouched. Just add code to replace my comment like. You have to store `TileType[][] map = getMap();` when your app starts, not inside the function.